# converting string to integer from file

Tags: python

I am asked to read lines from one file and print every other line from that file to another file. This is what i have so far.

```
my_file = open("thisFile.txt", "r")
out_file = open("thatFile.txt", "w")

for line in my_file:
    line = int(line)
    if line%2 !=0:
        print(line,file=out_file)     

my_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work and, if it throws an exception, what exception do you get?

Answer (score 4):

```
from itertools import islice

with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(islice(fin, None, None, 2)
```

Comment: +1 for clever, but I gotta say, "`islice(fin, None, None, 2)`" strikes me as the sort of code that makes no damn sense when you have to reread it six months later.  It's too bad you can't write `islice(fin, step=2)`.

Comment: @Zack it's not "clever" - it's a builtin that everyone should realise works in a certain sense. But yeah, agreed, shame it can't do that :(

Answer (score 1):

This is a relatively simple task - your main issue is the use of `int()` - you are trying to convert the entire line to a number, which is then failing. What you want to do is keep track the number of the line you are on. The easiest way to do this is with [the `enumerate()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
with open("thisFile.txt") as in_file, open("thatFile.txt") as out_file:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(in_file, start=1):
        if line_no % 2:
            out_file.write(line)
```

Note the use of the `with` statement here too - this automatically closes files, and will do so even if exceptions occur, it's good practice to use it. It's also significantly more readable.

Comment: @user2016535 Here is your chance to learn. It's a pretty simple bit of functionality.

Comment: @Lattyware It's bad pedagogy IMNSHO, but I have seen plenty of CS courses tell students that they _may not_ use constructs that the class hasn't gotten to yet.

Comment: because @Jon Clements answer is better.

Comment: @hd1 One answer being better does not make another answer bad. By all means, upvote his (I have), but downvoting an answer means that it is *bad*, which I don't feel my answer is.

Comment: I've upvoted this to bring it back to what it should be - it's not a wrong answer - whoever downvoted it should retract their vote

Comment: @Lattyware my answer was not ipso, facto, bad. OP didn't indicate his python version, so I gave a solution which would work in 1.5.2, unlike yours or the other one.

Comment: i can't use john clements answer i have not learned that either

Comment: @Zack Yeah, I've seen it personally where they penalize people for using standard library functionality. It's literally teaching people to write bad code. It's truly depressing.

Comment: @hd1 Really? 1.5.2? Answers should be focused at a version actually in any form of common usage. Unless specifically stated, it's pretty safe to assume everyone is on *at least* 2.6 - which is already two versions out of date.

Comment: @user2016535 I explained what the problem was in my post. Using my answer it should be easy enough to produce a version without using the `with` statement. StackOverflow is not somewhere to get people to do your homework for you. Please try and take the information we have given and use it to learn, not just expect to copy and paste an answer.

Comment: guys, i know there is a much simpler method. i just can't figure it out

Comment: @user2016535 we've taken time to answer your question - what you're allowed to do or not is not our concern - make your questions more explicit in the future

Comment: @Lattyware BTW you have a bug: iterating over a file doesn't trim newlines from the file, so you're inserting blank lines in the output.

Comment: @Zack Indeed, I actually edited that in after thinking it was needed for some reason. Corrected.

Comment: @Lattyware rather than bug you about it again I fixed another bug for you: if the OP's code had worked it woulda printed the first, third, fifth, ... lines but you were printing the second, fourth, sixth, ...

Answer (score 0):

The *minimal* change to your program to make it do what you want, bringing in no new concepts, is this:

```
my_file = open("thisFile.txt", "r")
out_file = open("thatFile.txt", "w")

i = 1
for line in my_file:
    if i % 2 != 0:
        print(line, file=out_file)
    i += 1

my_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

Your mistake was simply that you thought `int(line)` would give you the line number.  What that actually does is attempt to interpret the *text of each line* as an integer, which is not what you want.

Now, a great deal of Python's virtue lies in its enormous library of helpful functions.  The above works, but is not taking proper advantage of what the language has to offer.  The first thing I would change is to use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) rather than an explicit counter, the second thing I would change is to use the `write` method of files rather than `print`, and the third thing I would change is to take advantage of the "nonzero is true" rule:

```
my_file = open("thisFile.txt", "r")
out_file = open("thatFile.txt", "w")

for i, line in enumerate(my_file, start=1):
    if i % 2:
        out_file.write(line)

my_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

I said that this works, but really it only works unless something goes wrong.  If anything throws an exception (for instance, if an I/O error occurs) the file objects don't get closed.<sup>1</sup> The `with` statement tells Python to make sure that the files get closed, whether or not an exception happens; this is conveniently also less typing.

```
with open("thisFile.txt", "r") as my_file,
     open("thatFile.txt", "w") as out_file:
    for i, line in enumerate(my_file, start=1):
        if i % 2:
            out_file.write(line)
```

You may notice that this is the same as Lattyware's answer.  (Jon Clement's answer is maybe a little *too* clever; he appears to be [playing golf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf).)

<sup>1</sup> In this simple piece of code, if an exception happens CPython's garbage collector *will* notice that the file objects are no longer accessible and will close them for you, but this isn't something to rely on as your programs get more compicated.

Comment: Golfed version wouldn't bother importing itertools. Just read the whole file in to memory `fout.writelines(list(fin)[::2])`

Comment: Wasn't aware I was playing golf :) Unless using available tools/libs is playing golf now!

Comment: @JonClements See my comment on your answer.